# Windows XP don't recognize external disk formatted in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-xp, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have an external 2TB disk which I formatted on Windows 10 laptop and made one big NTFS partition. But when I connect the disk to the Windows XP laptop (SP3), it doesn't see the NTFS partition. This is how it looks in Disk manager (sorry, in czech):

[image]

it sees the physical disk, but not the partition, and it thinks that the disk is completely empty.

What is going on here?

1. Is it some new partition table format, which is not recognized by Windows XP?
2. Or, is the NTFS partition itself somehow too big for too something for Windows XP?

I guess it's more likely 1 than 2 because the Disk manager doesn't see the NTFS partition at all. Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows XP cannot read GPT disks, you will need to convert it to MBR, in order to use the disk in question.  The following [question](https://superuser.com/questions/292449/convert-a-gpt-disk-to-mbr-from-xp) explains how you can convert your disk, to Protective MBR, in order to use it within a 32-bit installation of Windows XP.

[Windows and GPT FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-and-gpt-faq)

> - Can the 32-bit version of Windows XP read, write, and boot from GPT
>     disks?
>
> **No. The 32-bit version will see only the Protective MBR. The EE
>   partition will not be mounted or otherwise exposed to application
>   software.**
>
> - Can Windows XP x64 read, write, and boot from GPT disks?
>
> **Windows XP x64 Edition can use GPT disks for data only.**

Comment: @Tomas He knows - like the rest of us - that XP 32-bit doesn't support GPT, only MBR. It has nothing to do with the size as you can have GPT in drives of *any* size. The opposite isn't true.

Comment: @Tomas - It was likely flagged as "it's no longer needed.", which is described as a comment, that is is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.